# table/table is not exported from the package in angular 14

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng, After updating the packages to latest version I am getting this Issue **table/table is not exported from the package** in angular 14.0.2.

```
        ./node_modules/library/fesm2020/library.mjs:133:0-29 - 
    Error: Module not found: 
    Error: Package path ./table/table is not exported from 
package D:\employee\node_modules\primeng (see exports field in D:\employee\node_modules\primeng\package.json)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have something like

```
import { Table } from 'primeng/table/table';
```

that apparently wasn't a problem in Angular 13, but *is* a problem in Angular 14. change it to `import { Table } from 'primeng/table';`

Answer (score 0):

according to their [milestones](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/milestones) Angular14 is not yet supported.

Comment: primeng has released the latest version 14.0.0.rc-1. Still it throw's same error